# How to send graphics to another form

Tags: c#, graphics

I have 2 forms and in those 2 forms i have two board.

In the first form user put some object on the board. And then it clicks next. I want to send the exact graphics to the other form so i can draw the same things in second form.

I've tried to use Graphics.Save() and Restore() functions, but didn't work. Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `Board` ? Give more details about the Forms. How are they related and instantiated ?

Comment: Board is a picture box, and then user puts some small pictures by dragging dropping them on the picture box. And i draw the pictures using graphics on pb. After that when user clicks next button, i create an object of second form. There is a picture box on the second form as well, so i want to draw the same graphics on this picture box as on the first form.

Comment: Graphics.Save/Restore only saves the state(or settings if you like) of the graphics object. Are your 2 forms in separate processes? If yes why don't you just pass the board object?

Comment: They are in the same project. And board object is just a pictureBox, even when i pass it, it doesn't show the graphics on it.

Comment: The Graphics class is *not* capable of storing a drawing.  You'll need a Bitmap.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it with Bitmap, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call Invalidate() on your second form to make the picture appear after you have passed it? If you minimise and then maximise your second form and the image appears, then that will be the problem.

Comment: Do you mean i should pass picturebox and then call Invalidate? if so i did, but no graphics again..

Comment: Have you tried saving to bitmap first as @Hans mentioned? I just tried saving pictureBox1 to a bitmap, then used a Graphics object to draw the bitmap onto pictureBox2 and it worked.